# How to set file value from datatransfer object

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the value of the file that is dragged and dropped to a field html:file property="file" . 
When I set the file value from dataTransfer object as below:

```
form.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var fileData = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    fileData.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
});
```

The above works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome browsers but not in IE11.

So I tried the below ways to see if I can get it working in IE11, but nothing worked on any of the browsers.

```
fileData.files[0] = event.dataTransfer.files[0];  //didn't work in any

fileData = event.dataTransfer; //didn't work in any

form.file.value = event.dataTransfer.files[0] //didn't work in any
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what is this `dataTransfer object` you speak of?

Comment: @JaromandaX https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer

Comment: yeah, thanks @Kaiido - the point was the code just used some random variable named `dataTransfer` as if it meant something. seeing it's the `event.dataTransfer` object, it makes more sense

Comment: @JaromandaX Edited the code to add event.dataTransfer. Sorry about that.